# Timer Animation Problem

Tags: .net, animation, timer, c++-cli

I am making a program using a `Timer` and a `PictureBox`. On each timer interval I want the PictureBox to move 1 unit to the right.

Here is my code:

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
  pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing ::Point (1, 28);
  bounceOne->Enabled = true;
}

private: System::Void bounceOne_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
  (pictureBox1->Location).X  = (pictureBox1->Location).X + 1;
}
```

However, at runtime this isn't doing what I want and don't know why it isn't working. Any advice?

Comment: Review your favorite .NET programming book about the differences between value and reference types.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying a temporary copy of the `Location` struct; your changes are thrown away.

Instead, you should increment the PictureBox's `Left` property.